# Touchpad sides not working Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: touchpad, 19.04, synaptics, hp-touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 today. The touchpad doesn't seem to be working properly. I have natural scrolling turned on and side scroll disabled. For some reason, the sides of touchpad doesn't work. If I start moving the cursor from sides (left or right) which is the scroll area , the cursor doesn't move at all. I can start from middle of touchpad and go to the very sides and it does move but starting from side does nothing.
The laptop model is HP Probook 440 G4 if that helps.

Comment: I was using Ubuntu 16.04 earlier and I had no such problem there, even in Windows, it works fine for me. Is this specific for 19.04?
I'll update the laptop description though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was using till today, now on 19.04
(It was 16.04 dual boot with Windows 10, now it's 19.04 dualboot)

Comment: ok well then it could be a 19.04 bug, disregard what I said. you should report this on launchpad

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having same problem in the future, it started working for me. I don't exactly know how it worked. I ran `synclient` command on ubuntu, after which I noticed it working. You'll probably get it correct if you mess around that command or change some properties( I didn't need to).

Comment: I've got the same issue but this has not helped. My machine is a 7th gen Lenovo X1 Carbon